# heroku: cannot switch back to my local machine branch from heroku branch

Tags: git, heroku, gitlab

I deployed my app to heroku and now I want to go back to my local **gitlab** branch and work there. I am stuck in master heroku branch.

I am not being able to go back to my local git branch. Is it possible?

when I do `git remote -v`  form main folder

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git (push)
origin  git@gitlab.com:raju/myapp.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.com:raju/myapp.git (push)
```

Comment: can u do `git remote -v` and add the results to ur question?

Comment: @Salman result added